# how to use jquery autocomplete twice on the same page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

My problem is that I am supposed to use jquery autocomplete library twice in the same page.

When I insert the first text field statically, autocomplete works fine. But if I want to insert second text field, the autocomplete results is shown where first text field takes place.

Both text fields have different names and ids, but still when I type a character in text field2, autocomplete results are shown below text field 1. What is wrong with my autocomplete function?

```
            var aramaKeyword = jQuery.trim($("#input_header_scroll_ara_keyword").val());
            $('#input_header_scroll_ara_keyword').val(aramaKeyword);

            $(function() {
                $("#input_header_scroll_ara_keyword").autocomplete({
                    source: function(request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: baseUrl + "<?php echo URL_ARAMA_AUTOCOMPLETE; ?>",
                            dataType: "json",
                            async: false,
                            data: {
                                q: jQuery.trim($("#input_header_scroll_ara_keyword").val())
                            },
                            success: function(data) {
                                response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                                    return {
                                        label: item,
                                        value: item
                                    }
                                }));                    
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    select: function(event, ui) {
                        var keyword = ui.item.value;
                        locateAraQuery('<?php echo URL_ARAMA; ?>', '<?php echo DEFAULT_STR_ARAMAQUERY_KEYWORD; ?>', '<?php echo lang('title_aradefaultkeyword'); ?>', keyword, '<?php echo ARAMA_SUFFIEX_BAR; ?>'); 
                    },

                    focus: function(event, ui) {
                        var keyword = ui.item.value;
                        $("#input_header_scroll_ara_keyword").val(keyword);             
                    },
                    minLength: 2,
                });
            });
```

Comment: did u try to put your multiple method in to a one function and call that function where u wanna use?

Comment: actually i have two different functions and each text field calls different function.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution.

```
appendTo: $("#input_header_scroll_ara_keyword").parent()
```

worked for me.